Is it possible to simplify/normalize nat arithmetic expressions in Coq?
I'm writing a tactic to apply some normalizing rewriting rules on a substitution algebra, similar to the autosubst project. I've made a sigma tactic that applies some rewriting rules, simplifying any possible substitution. However, as I'm dealing with polyadic binders, the tactic will often take goals like this:
1 goal
e : pseudoterm
i, j, k, l : nat
H : k <= l + j
H0 : l <= k
______________________________________(1/1)
lift i k (lift j l e) = lift (i + j) l e

And turn them into goals like this:
1 goal
e : pseudoterm
i, j, k, l : nat
H : k <= l + j
H0 : l <= k
______________________________________(1/1)
subst_lift (j - (k - l) + (i + k) - l) l e =
subst_lift (i + j) l e

The tactic searches for some terms of the algebra (such as lift and subst_lift in here) and rewrites it based on a series of rewriting rules presented to it. It operates on an abstract type X, which here is pseudoterm (but could be any type). Some of those rules, however, need to manipulate some natural number variables, and add additions and subtractions to the resulting terms. Overall, my tactic does exactly what I need.
One may note that the two terms above are the same, it's just a matter of running repeat (f_equal; try lia) on the resulting goal and it's done, as only natural number subterms differ but are decidably equal. So, my question is: as my goal is to just rewrite (not immediately solve, I'm using autorewrite actually), is there any way to simplify (and possibly normalize!) arithmetic on nat such as the one above, so that I could add this to my sigma tactic and just run reflexivity afterwards? In the above case, specifically, I'd like to automatically rewrite j - (k - l) + (i + k) - l to i + j, which lia can show to be equal.
I understand that subtraction on nat might be problematic, but those will be inserted by my tactic when there is some constraint that can be solved by lia and in general there won't be cases where I have a - b with b > a. I've tried searching for ring simplification on Coq to no avail.

Please do not post pictures of code. It's unreadable, unsearchable, and we can't help you with a picture.

@AndrejBauer, I had assumed it would be easier to illustrate it this way. I've edited my question.

Thanks. You assumed wrong :-) I am not going to say that links to GitHub are very unstable, and that it would be helpful to have at least some explanation of what pseudoterm and subst_lift are.

@AndrejBauer, I appreciate the feedback. The GitHub link is not really important, it's mostly for people curious on how I implemented the tactic. I've edited the question for further clarification; what I'm trying to do is to enhance my rewriting tactic to normalize nat arithmetic so that decidably equal terms are rewritten into the same form if possible (removing unecessary subtraction and addition).

So your question would still be the same if we just dropped subst_lift, correct? You're including it for dramatic effect.

@AndrejBauer, ok, I may have phrased my issue very poorly it seems, but yes.

I am just trying to understand what you're asking.

The ring_simplify tactic handles normalisation of ring expression just fine (the ring tactic basically simplifies expressions with ring_simplify, then uses reflexivity). It works out of the box for Z expressions:
Require Import Arith ZArith Ring.

Goal forall i j k l, (k <= l + j -> l <= k -> (j - (k - l) + (i + k) - l) =  (i + j))%Z.
Proof.
  intros.
  ring_simplify. (* (i + j)%Z = (i + j)%Z *)

The problem comes from the use of - on nat, of course: ring_simplify cannot handle those.
One simple option, if you can afford it, is to avoid - altogether: you say

in general there won't be cases where I have a - b with b > a

then do not use a - b, but instead introduce a new variable c and replace a - b with c and b with a + c. This is only possible if b is not a compound expression, but it might be a quick and easy solution.
If this is not possible, things are more complicated. One fancier possibility is to push your entire rewriting into Z, doing roughly the following:

replace a nat expression expr with Z.to_nat (Z.of_nat expr)
push all operation to Z, eg using Nat2Z.inj_sub for subtraction (which will generate an inequality that you can offload to lia)
use ring_simplify
push all operations back to nat

A number of tools already do similar manipulations to "move an expression between types", such as zify (used as preprocessing for lia and friends) and Trocq. However, I'm not sure they would actually do what you are after…

Couldn't one also introduce a new variable c and a new hypothesis a = b + c (and possibly a new obligation b <= a), and then use c instead of a - b? This way a and b can be arbitrary expressions, and the various tactics might still know what to do with the equational assumption (and OP does not seem worried about the additional obligation).

This might help, too! I'm afraid that ring_simplify only works on the goal though, it does not know about extra equality assumptions, which might be annoying…

Well, if it knew about extra equality assumptions then we enter the territory of quotients by ideals, Gröbner bases, and other scary algebra monsters.

Thanks for the answer. I did try the ring_simplify and couldn't make it to work, now I see why! I'm using lemmas of the form n >= i -> foo i n = bar (n - i) and then using autorewrite (which offloads new goals lia). I will try some post-processing steps to do as you suggest, possibly introducing a new variable. Otherwise, I'm going to try "moving the expression" to Z.
